# moq mongodb InsertOneAsync method

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, .net-core, moq

I am using Mongodb database with .net core. I just want to moq insert method that using `mongodbContext`. Here is what I am trying to do but it's not working:

```
public void InsertEventAsync_Test()
{
    //Arrange
    var eventRepository = EventRepository();
    var pEvent = new PlanEvent
    {
        ID = "testEvent",
        WorkOrderID = "WorkOrderID",
        IsDeleted = false,
        IsActive = true,
        EquipmentID = "EquipmentID"
    };
    ////Act


    //mockEventContext.Setup(mr => mr.PlanEvent.InsertOne(It.IsAny<PlanEvent>(), It.IsAny<InsertOneOptions>()))
    mockEventContext.Setup(s => s.PlanEvent.InsertOneAsync(It.IsAny<PlanEvent>(), It.IsAny<InsertOneOptions>())).Returns("sdad");
    var result = eventRepository.InsertEventAsync(pEvent);
    ////Assert
    result.Should().NotBeNull();
}
```

Below is the method that I need to Moq:

```
public EventRepository(IFMPContext eventContext)
{
    _eventContext = eventContext;
}

public async Task<string> InsertEventAsync(Model.EventDataModel.PlanEvent eventobj)
{
    eventobj._id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
    eventobj.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
    try
    {
        _eventContext.PlanEvent.InsertOne(eventobj);
        return eventobj.ID;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string x = ex.Message;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

```
public class EventRepository {
    private readonly IFMPContext eventContext;

    public EventRepository(IFMPContext eventContext) {
        this.eventContext = eventContext;
    }

    public async Task<string> InsertEventAsync(Model.EventDataModel.PlanEvent eventobj) {
        eventobj._id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
        eventobj.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
        try {
            await eventContext.PlanEvent.InsertOneAsync(eventobj);
            return eventobj.ID;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            string x = ex.Message;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

You need to configure the test to support the async nature of the method under test

```
public async Task InsertEventAsync_Test()
{
    //Arrange
    var expected = "testEvent";
    var pEvent = new PlanEvent {
        ID = expected,
        WorkOrderID = "WorkOrderID",
        IsDeleted = false,
        IsActive = true,
        EquipmentID = "EquipmentID"
    };

    var mockEventContext = new Mock<IFMPContext>();
    mockEventContext
        .Setup(_ => _.PlanEvent.InsertOneAsync(It.IsAny<PlanEvent>(), It.IsAny<InsertOneOptions>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(Task.FromResult((object)null));

    var eventRepository = new EventRepository(mockEventContext.Object);

    //Act
    var actual = await eventRepository.InsertEventAsync(pEvent);

    //Assert
    actual.Should().NotBeNull()
    actual.Should().Be(expected);

}
```

The test method definition needed to be updated to be asynchronous to allow the method under test to be awaited. The mock dependency also needed to be setup in such a way to allow the async flow to continue as expected when invoked.

Answer (score 0):

@Nkosi Thanks a lot for your help. Finally i found the way. i was missing extra moq param `It.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>()`  below is the working test

```
    public void InsertEventAsync_Test()
        {
            //Arrange
            var eventRepository = EventRepository();
            var pEvent = new PlanEvent
            {
                ID = "testEvent",
                WorkOrderID = "WorkOrderID",
                IsDeleted = false,
                IsActive = true,
                EquipmentID = "EquipmentID"
            };
            ////Act

            mockEventContext.Setup(s => s.PlanEvent.InsertOne(It.IsAny<PlanEvent>(), It.IsAny<InsertOneOptions>(),It.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>()));
            var result = eventRepository.InsertEventAsync(pEvent);
            ////Assert
            result.Should().NotBeNull();
            Assert.AreEqual(pEvent.ID, result);

        }
```